# File upload in php for .JPG, .PNG Extensions

Tags: php

I read [Image uploader, capital letters in JPG extension doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16252903/image-uploader-jpg/16253193) but i need to upload .JPG files in my file uploading system.

Here is my Code :

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" , "JPG");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/JPG")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

How can i change my code to make **.JPG, .PNG files** upload to my the upload directory ?

Error i am getting is invalid files if i choose .JPG files to upload.

Crazy try : I can't even upload if i change my code like this.

```
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png" , "JPG");
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/JPG")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, this will help You (I hope)

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/660367/PHP-image-uploader-with-display-insert

[http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/660367/PHP-image-uploader-with-display-insert)

Comment: Your link is ok, But what i want is , I need answer for my question.

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you are having problems with uppercase extensions, then try converting the extension to lowercase in your conditions by using [strtolower()](http://www.php.net/strtolower), like:

```
...
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/JPG")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowedExts))
{
...//rest of your code
```

Comment: No, Its still showing the same error even i converted to strtolower($extension).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $temp = $_FILES["file"]["name"];    
    $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "gif", "bmp", "JPG", "PNG", "GIF", "BMP");
    list($txt, $ext) = explode(".", $temp);

    if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats)){

     if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0){
        echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
     }
     else{
      echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
      echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
      echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
      echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
}
else{
  echo "Invalid file";
}
```

Try this code it may help you....

Comment: This too have the same problem. "Invalid File".

Comment: **Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /opt/lampp/htdocs/z/dca_1/admin/fileupload/file_uploader.php** This is the error i am getting now

Comment: add this line `$temp = $_FILES["file"]["name"];` instead of  `$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(file_exists($path_image) && in_array(exif_imagetype($path_image),array(1, 2, 3, 6))){ ... }
```

validate file exists and the type image

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php